# Keras: How to stop training with the lowest observed metric value?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras

With Keras, I would like to stop the training at the epoch which returns the best (in most cases: lowest) observed metric (such as val_loss for example). I would **not** like to use the state of the network *after* the patience "ran out".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Well.... you can't really "stop" at the best accuracy, because you need to know the future values to decide if there will be better values!

But you can use another callback, the [ModelCheckpoint](https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint), to save your model after each epoch.

You can pass the argument `save_best_only` so the model will only be saved when the monitored value (in your case `'val_loss'`) is better than the last saved model.

After training, you can load the saved model: `keras.models.load_model(filepath)`

If you have problems loading a saved model like that, you can try to use `save_weights_only=True` in the callback. And then you'd load the weights with `model.load_weights(filepath)`.