# How to use weights from a specific epoc in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I am running 50 epocs for a Neural Network using Keras.

Here's my verbose response to it.
You can see that Epoc 47 (`loss: 0.0065 - acc: 0.9980`) has a much higher Accuracy and lesser cost that the last epoc and thus more suitable.

I am new to Keras, and would like to know if it is possible to use the instance of the model model in a particular epoc (in this case, epoc 47) instead of the final one?

**EDIT**: I do not want to run the training again with epoc = 47, that seems like a waste of time and resource.

```
Epoch 1/50
 - 32s - loss: 0.4603 - acc: 0.8541
Epoch 2/50
 - 31s - loss: 0.1140 - acc: 0.9655
Epoch 3/50
 - 31s - loss: 0.0805 - acc: 0.9754
Epoch 4/50
 - 38s - loss: 0.0663 - acc: 0.9792
Epoch 5/50
 - 47s - loss: 0.0551 - acc: 0.9829
Epoch 6/50
 - 39s - loss: 0.0487 - acc: 0.9846
Epoch 7/50
 - 38s - loss: 0.0454 - acc: 0.9853
Epoch 8/50
 - 37s - loss: 0.0399 - acc: 0.9873
Epoch 9/50
 - 42s - loss: 0.0376 - acc: 0.9881
Epoch 10/50
 - 42s - loss: 0.0332 - acc: 0.9896
Epoch 11/50
 - 41s - loss: 0.0333 - acc: 0.9893
Epoch 12/50
 - 39s - loss: 0.0286 - acc: 0.9911
Epoch 13/50
 - 36s - loss: 0.0281 - acc: 0.9905
Epoch 14/50
 - 35s - loss: 0.0258 - acc: 0.9918
Epoch 15/50
 - 37s - loss: 0.0250 - acc: 0.9915
Epoch 16/50
 - 35s - loss: 0.0236 - acc: 0.9920
Epoch 17/50
 - 41s - loss: 0.0212 - acc: 0.9932
Epoch 18/50
 - 33s - loss: 0.0219 - acc: 0.9928
Epoch 19/50
 - 36s - loss: 0.0198 - acc: 0.9935
Epoch 20/50
 - 37s - loss: 0.0172 - acc: 0.9941
Epoch 21/50
 - 35s - loss: 0.0187 - acc: 0.9938
Epoch 22/50
 - 38s - loss: 0.0182 - acc: 0.9939
Epoch 23/50
 - 33s - loss: 0.0163 - acc: 0.9945
Epoch 24/50
 - 35s - loss: 0.0148 - acc: 0.9949
Epoch 25/50
 - 33s - loss: 0.0148 - acc: 0.9951
Epoch 26/50
 - 37s - loss: 0.0143 - acc: 0.9951
Epoch 27/50
 - 36s - loss: 0.0143 - acc: 0.9949
Epoch 28/50
 - 34s - loss: 0.0129 - acc: 0.9958
Epoch 29/50
 - 36s - loss: 0.0112 - acc: 0.9962
Epoch 30/50
 - 34s - loss: 0.0112 - acc: 0.9961
Epoch 31/50
 - 34s - loss: 0.0144 - acc: 0.9954
Epoch 32/50
 - 40s - loss: 0.0132 - acc: 0.9952
Epoch 33/50
 - 40s - loss: 0.0107 - acc: 0.9964
Epoch 34/50
 - 43s - loss: 0.0118 - acc: 0.9958
Epoch 35/50
 - 36s - loss: 0.0113 - acc: 0.9961
Epoch 36/50
 - 34s - loss: 0.0101 - acc: 0.9963
Epoch 37/50
 - 37s - loss: 0.0102 - acc: 0.9966
Epoch 38/50
 - 37s - loss: 0.0098 - acc: 0.9965
Epoch 39/50
 - 35s - loss: 0.0097 - acc: 0.9966
Epoch 40/50
 - 35s - loss: 0.0102 - acc: 0.9963
Epoch 41/50
 - 34s - loss: 0.0081 - acc: 0.9972
Epoch 42/50
 - 36s - loss: 0.0075 - acc: 0.9976
Epoch 43/50
 - 32s - loss: 0.0075 - acc: 0.9975
Epoch 44/50
 - 32s - loss: 0.0088 - acc: 0.9971
Epoch 45/50
 - 31s - loss: 0.0107 - acc: 0.9968
Epoch 46/50
 - 32s - loss: 0.0089 - acc: 0.9970
Epoch 47/50
 - 33s - loss: 0.0065 - acc: 0.9980
Epoch 48/50
 - 30s - loss: 0.0076 - acc: 0.9975
Epoch 49/50
 - 30s - loss: 0.0073 - acc: 0.9978
Epoch 50/50
 - 30s - loss: 0.0090 - acc: 0.9971
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48460755/how-earlystopping-can-be-used-to-stop-at-that-epoch-which-gives-best-val-accuray/48460951#48460951

Comment: @DanielMöller Looks like that should do the job, will implement and check.